# Arrange z order of two movieclips on click

Tags: actionscript-3

i have 2 layes with one movieclip each.

How is it possible to bring forward the clickable movie clip and the other goes backwards?

I tried some methods but i didn't had any luck.

If it is not too much code and someone has a little time please help me to solve it.

Thank you all again!

Comment: Please post some code, for example the Code that did not work

Comment: Slimply use the method `addChild` or `addChildAt`, to reorder the display list. If you use `addChild` the child automatically will move to the top of the display list and removed from its current position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put both movie clip in arraylist suppose we say (zorder),and call bringttofronthandler or sendtobackhandler on some event as you wish.

```
    private function recalculateDepth():void
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < zorder.length; i++) 
            {
                zorder.getItemAt(i).depth = i;
            }
        }
        protected function bringToFrontHandler(event:Event):void
        { 

                zorder.removeItem(selectedItem);
                //set to top of array
                zorder.addItem(selectedItem);
                recalculateDepth();


        }
   protected function sendToBackHandler(event:Event):void
        {

                zorder.removeItem(selectedItem);
                //set to bottom of array
                zorder.addItemAt(selectedItem, 0);
                recalculateDepth();
            }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

swapChildren() or swapChildrenAt();

```
this.swapChildren(mc1,mc2)
```

or

```
this.swapChildrenAt(0,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check these links to understand the concept of display lists.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/display_list_programming_as3.edu.html

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3displaylist

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/as3-101the-display-list/

All these will help you understand the operations that you can perform on various objects on screen including the swap functionality that you are asking for.